# Can I use my Raspberry Pi as an AirPlay receiver?

Tags: streaming-video, streaming

Can the Raspberry Pi be used as an AirPlay receiver for video? 
Can I stream media from my iTunes library, or play a video from an iOS device via Airplay on the Pi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fully support video/audio or music from your `i` device the best thing out there currently is `XBMC` or better known for Raspberry as [RaspBMC](http://www.raspbmc.com/)

You can install RaspBMC by using the [Pi foundations NOOB's installer](http://www.raspberrypi.org/introducing-noobs/).

[image]

Its pretty simple, once its installed, **requires network access**, everything else is enabled via the BMC GUI.

Then in RaspBMC you need to enable Airplay once.

> Enable it under System > Network > “Allow XBMC to receive AirPlay
>   content”

Here is how it will look on your idevice, while watching a stream that is castable.

[image]

[Here is a video on a demonstration of how it works.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrSfqOWETv8)

Comment: Can anyone confirm whether or not this option allows video streaming now?

Comment: I am also having trouble to stream video. Audio works, but video doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Audio only on Raspbian. I have done this before with `shairport` and it worked very well with audio streaming.

Before we can install shairport we need to get a few dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install git libao-dev libssl-dev libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl libwww-perl avahi-utils libmodule-build-perl
```

Then we have to install an iOS6 update. You can skip this if you not using iOS 6

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/njh/perl-net-sdp.git perl-net-sdp
cd perl-net-sdp
perl Build.PL
sudo ./Build
sudo ./Build test
sudo ./Build install
cd ..
```

OK. Finally we can get the latest shairport code from GIT and build it. Once its built you should move the binary to your home directory since `/tmp` will be erased after a reboot or you can download and build it in `/home/src`

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/abrasive/shairport
cd shairport
make
```

You can run shairport. `AirPi` is a name, you can change it to whatever you like ;)

```
./shairport.pl -a AirPi
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest you rename Shairplay in Shairport in your answer. Also, the most current releases are to be found over at https://github.com/abrasive/shairport

Comment: The OP also asked about video, which, IIRC, is not possible with Shairport alone...

Comment: Thanks. I updated that with your suggestions. I missed the video part

Comment: Shairport can now be found as shairport-sync https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync